# Calculate the expectation of randomization after randomly taking out the element

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, integer-programming

Suppose we have two vectors $X = \{x_1, x_2, ....,x_n\}$ and $R = \{r_1, r_2, ...., r_n\}$ with $\sum_i^n{x_i} \leq 1$ and $0 \leq x_i \leq 1$. For $R$, we have $R \geq 0$, i.e. for all i, $r_i \geq 0$.

Then we have the operation called randomization here that let's pick up any element inside X with probability $P(x_k \mbox{ is picked}) = \frac{x_k}{\sum_i^n{x_i}}$, change the value of $x_i$ to 1 and the rest of elements in X to be $0$. Then the vector X is converted to $X^* = \{x^*_1, x^*_2, ....,x^*_n\}, x^*_i \in \{0,1\}$ Then we can know that $E[X^*R^T] = E[\sum_i^n{r_ix^*_i}] = \sum_i^n{r_iE[x^*_i]} \geq \sum_i^n{r_ix_i} = XR^T$

Then let's select an element $x_j$ inside X randomly with probability $P = \frac{x_j}{\sum_i^n{x_i}}$ and change its value to $0$, giving us $X_{new} = \{x_1, x_2, ..., x_{j-1}, 0, x_{j+1}, ...,x_n\}$. Let's repeat the same operation as described above to $X_{new}$, what can we say about the relationship between $E[X^*_{new}R^T]$ and $XR^T$? Ideally, I want to prove that $E[X^*_{new}R^T] \geq XR^T$.

Greatly appreciate any comments and hints!

Comment: With your definitions $X_{new}^*$ is $(n-1)$-dimensional, so the product $X_{new}^* R^\top$ is not well-defined. Perhaps you can define $X_{new}$ differently. Instead of removing $x_j$ from the original vector, you could change it to zero?

Comment: I assume that there are some restriction on $R$ too? such as $r_i \geq 0$ for all $i$ ?

Comment: @jakobdt, yes, you're right, let me edit it!

Comment: @LeanderTilstedKristensen, thanks! yes, this is a valid assumption. edited

Answer (score 0):

Let $x_i^{new}$ be the $i^{th}$ index of $X_{new}$.
\begin{align*} E[X^*_{new}R^T] =  E[\sum x_i^{new}r_i] =\sum E[x_i^{new} r_i]\\
= \sum r_iE[x_i^{new}] = \sum r_i(0\cdot P(x_i^{new}=0)+x_i\cdot P(x_i^{new}=x_i))\\
= \sum r_ix_i(1-\frac{x_i}{\sum x_i})= \sum r_ix_i-\frac{\sum r_ix_i^2}{\sum x_i} \leq \sum r_ix_i=XR^T.
\end{align*}
All the sums are take on the index set $\{1, 2, \dots, n\}$.

Comment: @Martin, thanks so much for the comment, but I've spotted an issue. Please correct me if I’m wrong. 

The first thing is that I think the second line of your proof should be $\sum{r_iE[x^{new}_i]} = \sum{ri(0\times P(x_i^{new} = 0) + 1 \times P(x_i^{new} = 1))}$
Right? Since when we operate on $X_{new}$ to convert it to $X^{*}_{new}$, the element ${X^{*}_{new}}_{i} \in \{0,1\}$.